# Javascript object referencing last object of kind instead of itself

Tags: javascript, object

I have a javascript object which i am instantiating for each instance of a dom object.  My code looks something like this

```
let div = null;

$(function() {
    div = {
        init: function(container) {
            this.loadDom(container);
            this.loadEvents();
        },

        loadDom:function(container) {
            this.$container = $(container);
            this.$buttons = this.$container.find('.button');
            this.$textPanel = $('.text-panel')
        },

        loadEvents: function() {
            let that = this;

            // output the item's id. This works correctly
            that.$textPanel.append(that.$container.attr('id') + '<br>');

            this.$buttons.on('click', function() {

                // output the item's id. This always outputs the last item
                that.$textPanel.append(that.$container.attr('id') + '<br>');
            });
        }
    };

    let divs = $('.item');
    if(divs.length > 0) {
        divs.each(function(){
            div.init(this);
        })
    }
});
```

[here is a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9Lrc2jub/)

I expect there to be one object created for each div with a class of 'item', and all the functions within that object to apply to that one div. i.e. when you click the red div, the container's id should be shown in the panel below.

In the loadEvents function, I list the id of the current div. This is run immediately and correctly lists "modal-1" and "modal-2". But when I run the same command after a button click, the id of the last div is always displayed rather than the current div.

How can I make the button click work so the id of the correct div is shown?

Thanks

Comment: From a very first look, I can see that `div.init` is called multiple times, so the last call will always win upon the others, since `div.$container` will always be **the last div called in the foreach**.

Comment: If i change the line to `that.$textPanel.append($(this).closest('.item').attr('id') + '<br>');` the correct id is displayed, so the individual objects clearly still exist.  It is just the variable `that` which is overwritten

Comment: I have reviewed your code to make each `div` instance unique, and added the `let` before `that`, otherwise it's an **implicit global**. This works as expected, now: https://jsfiddle.net/pe431ksr/

Comment: @briosheje. Wowza. As simple as that. I have been scratching my head for hours over this. Thanks so much for your help

Comment: feel free to accept my answer below if you want to, so that the question will be marked as answered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have reviewed the code by making `div` a function instead, so that the scope of each div will be unique and the events registered will belong to the div itself.

Other than that, the variable `that` was implicitly global, so I've added `let` before it so that it's correctly scoped.

It now works as intended

```js
let div = null;

$(function() {
 div = function(){
   return {
      init: function(container) {
        this.loadDom(container);
        this.loadEvents();
      },

      loadDom:function(container) {
        this.$container = $(container);
        console.log('con')
        this.$buttons = this.$container.find('.button');
        this.$textPanel = $('.text-panel')
      },

      loadEvents: function() {
        let that = this;

        // output the item's id. This works correctly
        that.$textPanel.append(that.$container.attr('id') + '<br>');

        this.$buttons.on('click', function() {

          // output the item's id. This always outputs the last item
          that.$textPanel.append(that.$container.attr('id') + '<br>');
        });
      }
    }
  }


 let divs = $('.item');
  if(divs.length > 0) {
   divs.each(function(){
     const _d = new div();
     _d.init(this);
    })
  }
})
```

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 30px;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
}

.item {
  border: 1px dotted green;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
}

.button {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  background: red;
  cursor: pointer
}

.text-panel {
  border: 1px dotted black;
  height: 200px;
  grid-column: 1/3;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="item" id="modal-1">
   <div class="button">click me</div>
   modal-1
  </div>
  <div class="item" id="modal-2">
   <div class="button">click me</div>
   modal-2
  </div>
  <div class="text-panel"></div>
</div>
```